# Find element by Xpath and store it as a string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying find element by Xpath on the web page and store it as a String to use it later. 
I'm stacked at this.
I think my code is not doing the right thing. Its open the Url doing the search that i need but not storing any elements, or it just simply cannot find it

Could you please help me with it
Thanks!

my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import com.Uiproject.flickr.APIprop;


public class renaming {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        String baseUrl;
        Client client;
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        String FlickrUrl = APIprop.flickrurl;
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = client.target(FlickrUrl)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
        String content = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(content);
        JSONObject jsonresponse = XML.toJSONObject(content)
                .getJSONObject("rsp").getJSONObject("photos")
                .getJSONObject("photo");

        String title = jsonresponse.getString("title");

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.airliners.net";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("q")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("q")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys(title);
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();

        new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("sort_order")))
                .selectByVisibleText("Latest Additions First");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"photo_id desc\"]"))
                .click();
        List<WebElement> resultList = driver
                .findElements(By
                        .xpath(".//html/body/div/div[3]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/font/a[1]"));
        for (WebElement resultItem : resultList) {
            String tabname = resultItem.getText();
            System.out.println(tabname);
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

The problem was in the Xpath 
The correct one is as follow:
`//div[@id='content']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]`

thanks everybody!

Comment: The issue seems to be in your XPath. Use relative XPath if possible.

Comment: Can you tell please what exactly do you want to retrieve? Is it all Aircraft names ?

Comment: Are you sure ur xpath is correct? It seems your xpath, if correct will return only 1 element (a[1])